# Why can my functional test not see my methods created using define_method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, functional-testing

I have this in my application_controller.rb:

```
Group.all.each do |g|
  define_method( "is_#{ g.name }?".to_sym ) do
    unless @current_user.in_group?( g.name )
      flash[:notice] = "You must be in the #{ g.name.titleize } group to access that page"
      redirect_to '/'
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

It uses entries in my groups table to create methods on the fly.

My problem is my functional tests can't see those methods:

```
  1) Error:
test_has_an_index(Sc::QuestionsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_admin?' for #<Sc::QuestionsController:0x000000067749c0>
```

What do I need to do so my functional tests can see my dynamically created methods?

Comment: Can you add the code you use to call these methods in your application and in the tests?

Comment: Does it work if you test it in the console ? `ApplicationController.new.is_admin?`

Comment: The code I use to call these methods is a before filter in a controller:

before_filter :is_admin?

ApplicationController.new.is_admin? cannot be found either.

(rdb:1) ApplicationController.new.is_admin?
*** Unknown command: "ApplicationController.new.is_admin?".  Try "help".